# Java Swing to JavaFX (RMI/Threads)

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

Currently teaching myself advanced object programming and I've hit a snag when trying to write a Javafx solution to a given Swing solution.

The problem was to develop an RMI program with Polling. I have the Swing version working perfectly, and I believe I've narrowed the problem down this section of code.

Swing

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() 
        {
            new PollClient().setVisible(true);
        }
      });
}
```

JavaFx

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                launch(args);
            }
        });
    }
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Platform.runLater` specifies in its documentation that it executed on the `JavaFX application thread` at an unspecified time in the future. For this thread to exist you must first launch your application.

This means that since the application isnt launched the action to launch the application is never executed.

Regardless, JavaFX should be launched from within the main function, no need to insert a delay:

`Application.launch(PollClient.class, args)`